# ssh "Acess denied" password doesn't work (B+), have tried new charger, sudo passwd pi, etc

Tags: raspbian, ssh, raspi-config

I have a raspi b+ with the password pi (i reset this password to check) and try to ssh using putty. I have tried raspi-config and using high-quality phone charger. Nothing works: I get this error message:

> Access denied

I'm using Raspbian and trying to ssh on windows 8.1.

Any troubleshooting ideas? I have also overvolted +8 and overclocked to 1500 MHz. could this be involved?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to look at stuff in the pi's root filesystem, which means either plugging in a keyboard and display or taking the SD card out.

Do the `ssh` thing, then check `/var/log/secure` to see if there is a more informative message than "Access denied".  Note this file is readable only by root (try `sudo cat ...`). Also have a look at:

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog | grep sshd
```

Finally, `sshd` is configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  By default it should be set to allow for password authentication but you can check.  You need to find this line:

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

It can be like that (commented out, since the default is "yes"), but it shouldn't be uncommented and set to "no".  You also need:

```
UsePAM yes
```

Which is probably already there.